# How to push td in array es6 reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I staring to build the some project but the ploblem is i can't push the  tag to the array

```
const createData = _.map(this.props.users, (user, index) => {
      let array = []
      _.map(user.user, (i, index2) => {
        array.push(
          <td>{i.name}</td>
          <td>{i.total_hour}</td>
          <td>{i.manday}</td>
        )
      })
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{user.position}</td>
          {array}
        </tr>
      )
    })
```

How does the way can i do that

Answer (score 1):

jsx doesn't support this following syntax, you should a parent to include them.

```
<td>{i.name}</td>
<td>{i.total_hour}</td>
<td>{i.manday}</td>
```

So you should change your code like this way:

```
const createData = _.map(this.props.users, (user, index) => {
  let array = []
  _.map(user.user, (i, index2) => {
    array.concat([i.name, i.total_hour, i.manday])
  })
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{user.position}</td>
      {
        array.map((one, i) => {
          reutrn <td key={i}>one</td>
        })
      }
    </tr>
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[***.map***](http://underscorejs.org/#map) returns an array. You can use [**.each**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and push each element like this.

```
const createData = _.map(this.props.users, (user, index) => {
  let array = []
  _.each(user.user, (i, index2) => {
    array.push(
      <td>{i.name}</td>
      <td>{i.total_hour}</td>
      <td>{i.manday}</td>
    )
  })
})
```